# Bootstrap 3 Carousel fading to new slide instead of sliding to new slide

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 3, unmodified.

Here's

```
<!-- Carousel
================================================== -->
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active carousel-1">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Example headline.</h1>
          <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Sign up today</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item carousel-2">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
          <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Learn more</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
</div><!-- /.carousel -->
```

default css from bootstrap 3:

```
.carousel {
  position: relative;
}

.carousel-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.carousel-inner > .item {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out left;
          transition: 0.6s ease-in-out left;
}

.carousel-inner > .item > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
}

.carousel-inner > .active,
.carousel-inner > .next,
.carousel-inner > .prev {
  display: block;
}

.carousel-inner > .active {
  left: 0;
}

.carousel-inner > .next,
.carousel-inner > .prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.carousel-inner > .next {
  left: 100%;
}

.carousel-inner > .prev {
  left: -100%;
}

.carousel-inner > .next.left,
.carousel-inner > .prev.right {
  left: 0;
}

.carousel-inner > .active.left {
  left: -100%;
}

.carousel-inner > .active.right {
  left: 100%;
}

.carousel-control {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 15%;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  opacity: 0.5;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}

.carousel-control.left {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 top, 100% top, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0001)));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, color-stop(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0), color-stop(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0001) 100%));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0001) 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0001) 100%);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#80000000', endColorstr='#00000000', GradientType=1);
}

.carousel-control.right {
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 top, 100% top, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0001)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, color-stop(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0001) 0), color-stop(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 100%));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0001) 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0001) 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 100%);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#80000000', GradientType=1);
}

.carousel-control:hover,
.carousel-control:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 0.9;
  filter: alpha(opacity=90);
}

.carousel-control .icon-prev,
.carousel-control .icon-next,
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left,
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 5;
  display: inline-block;
}

.carousel-control .icon-prev,
.carousel-control .icon-next {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  font-family: serif;
}

.carousel-control .icon-prev:before {
  content: '\2039';
}

.carousel-control .icon-next:before {
  content: '\203a';
}

.carousel-indicators {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 15;
  width: 60%;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-left: -30%;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
}

.carousel-indicators li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 1px;
  text-indent: -999px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.carousel-indicators .active {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.carousel-caption {
  position: absolute;
  right: 15%;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 15%;
  z-index: 10;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.carousel-caption .btn {
  text-shadow: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .carousel-control .icon-prev,
  .carousel-control .icon-next {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  .carousel-caption {
    right: 20%;
    left: 20%;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
  }
  .carousel-indicators {
    bottom: 20px;
  }
}
```

some css that I've added:

```
    .carousel {
  height: 500px;
}
.carousel-inner {
  height: 100%;
}

.carousel-1 {
  height: 100%;
  background: url(../images/carousel1.jpg)  no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.carousel-2 {
  height: 100%;
  background: url(../images/carousel2.jpg)  no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

but I can't figure out how I can this carousel with fading effect.
I tried to change opacity from 1 to 0, when active item, but it makes 2 animations, it slides left and changes opacity too..

Can you help me?

Comment: You'll have to edit the carousel.js file in bootstrap to get a fading effect because sliding is the default and there isn't an option for fading that you can pass in.

Comment: @user2606561 please credit the best answer... the answer of gerardnll does not require any touching of libraries, just add the code

Answer (score 102):

The update from 3.2.x to 3.3.x broke some of the solutions explained here and on other threads because of the change: "*Added transforms to improve carousel performance in modern browsers.*"

If you are using **Bootstrap 3.3.x** there's a solution here:
http://codepen.io/transportedman/pen/NPWRGq

Basically you need to add the "carousel-fade" class to your carousel so that you have:
 `<div class="carousel slide carousel-fade">`

And then include the following CSS:

```
/*
  Bootstrap Carousel Fade Transition (for Bootstrap 3.3.x)
  CSS from:       http://codepen.io/transportedman/pen/NPWRGq
  and:            http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548731/bootstrap-3-carousel-fading-to-new-slide-instead-of-sliding-to-new-slide
  Inspired from:  http://codepen.io/Rowno/pen/Afykb 
*/
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .item {
  opacity: 0;
  transition-property: opacity;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.right {
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .next.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .prev.right {
  opacity: 1;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-control {
  z-index: 2;
}

/*
  WHAT IS NEW IN 3.3: "Added transforms to improve carousel performance in modern browsers."
  Need to override the 3.3 new styles for modern browsers & apply opacity
*/
@media all and (transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d) {
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.next,
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.active.right {
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
              transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.prev,
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.active.left {
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
              transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.next.left,
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.prev.right,
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.active {
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
              transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @gerardnll, that was exactly what I was looking for.  Have added a full code snippet for easy reference.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work for me.
But how do you change the fade time?

Comment: If you add "transform:none;" (and its prefixed version) to your third and fourth rule, you can get rid of the whole media query.

Comment: To adjust the `transition-duration`, specify this in the `.item` rule: for example `.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .item { ...; transition-duration: 2s}`.  I must admit that the transitions are much smoother in bootstrap 3.2 than in 3.3; I need to dig into it deeper though.  I'm sticking with 3.2 until I sort it out.

Comment: Also worth noting you need the `slide` class for this to work. In the JS is checks for this class. Found this example: http://codepen.io/transportedman/pen/NPWRGq

Comment: Great solution worked perfectly for me.  To add an interval and control the transition speed you can use the following code snippet at the bottom of the page above the </body> tag:

`<script>
    $('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 7000 //changes the speed
    })
    </script>`

Comment: Very elegant solution. No extra js! Thanks. Please add the slide class to your example though

Answer (score 42):

This can be accomplished using only CSS. To change the carousel to a fade transition instead of slide, use **one** of the following snippets (LESS or standard CSS).

**LESS**

```
// Fade transition for carousel items
.carousel {
  .item {
    left: 0 !important;
    .transition(opacity .4s); //adjust timing here
  }
  .carousel-control {
    background-image: none; // remove background gradients on controls
  }
  // Fade controls with items
  .next.left,
  .prev.right {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  .active.left,
  .active.right {
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 2;
  }
}
```

**Plain CSS:**

```
/* Fade transition for carousel items */
.carousel .item {
    left: 0 !important;
      -webkit-transition: opacity .4s; /*adjust timing here */
         -moz-transition: opacity .4s;
           -o-transition: opacity .4s;
              transition: opacity .4s;
}
.carousel-control {
    background-image: none !important; /* remove background gradients on controls */
}
/* Fade controls with items */
.next.left,
.prev.right {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1;
}
.active.left,
.active.right {
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: I can confirm that the Plain CSS solution here also works when overriding bootstrap captions to make css animation for them, works real smooth and is very effective.

Comment: This answer don't apply to BS3.1.
I've found the correct one : http://codepen.io/Rowno/pen/Afykb

Comment: It seem to work fine, but it fades instaltly. I tryed to change the timing, but it seems nothing happends. The fade time is almost instant..and i need something smoother. Can you help me please?

Comment: This answer is great, but it's weird it works in Dev mode, not in production, any thoughts on why? @JoeConlin

Answer (score 20):

Some good answers, but the problem with all solutions I have tried is that the images don´t fade into each other. Instead, the first one fades completely out and than the next one fades in.

1. In the HTML code change from .slide to .fade on the .carousel element
2. Add this in the css:

```
    .carousel.fade {
         opacity: 1;
    }
    .carousel.fade .item {
        transition: opacity ease-out .7s;
        left: 0;
        opacity: 0; /* hide all slides */
        top: 0;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
    }
    .carousel.fade .item:first-child {
        top: auto;
        opacity: 1; /* show first slide */
        position: relative;
    }
    .carousel.fade .item.active {
        opacity: 1;
    }
```

Comment: Nice & simple css solution,  exactly what I needed.

Comment: Brilliant, you saved me digging around for another plugin, thank you very much

Comment: one of the few times I needed a copy/paste solution for a desperate quick fix - thanks - my brain had given up for the evening!

Answer (score 7):

You can achieve a fade effect (instead of sticking with the default slide) using css only.
Add these to your stylesheet

```
.carousel .item {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 3s; 
    -moz-transition: opacity 3s; 
    -ms-transition: opacity 3s; 
    -o-transition: opacity 3s; 
    transition: opacity 3s;
}
.carousel .active.left {
    left:0;opacity:0;z-index:2;
}
.carousel .next {
    left:0;opacity:1;z-index:1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

for bootstrap 3, this is what i used

```
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .item {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition-property: opacity;
  -moz-transition-property: opacity;
  -o-transition-property: opacity;
  transition-property: opacity;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active {
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.right {
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .next.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .prev.right {
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-control {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use transition in css3:

```html
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .item {
  -webkit-transition-property: opacity;
  transition-property: opacity;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .item,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.right {
  opacity: 0;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .next.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .prev.right {
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .next,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .prev,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.right {
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-control {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the plain .css. It worked great. Note that I deleted the following from the bootstrap.min.css:

```
/* Fade transition for carousel items */

.carousel .item {
   left: 0 !important;
   -webkit-transition: opacity .4s;
    /*adjust timing here */ 
   -moz-transition: opacity .4s; 
   -o-transition: opacity .4s; 
   transition: opacity .4s; 
}

.carousel-control { 
   background-image: none !important; 
   /* remove background gradients on controls */ 
} 

/* Fade controls with items */

.next.left, .prev.right {
   opacity: 1; 
   z-index: 1;
}

.active.left, .active.right {
   opacity: 0;
   z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: I realize this is a late comment, but for the sake of other devs reading this, it's bad practice to modify any 3rd party library. Instead, you should "override" the styling in your own css file.

Answer (score 1):

In reply to [gerardnll](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26907841/5027029)'s answer the Less code to extend Bootstrap 3.3.x carousel by fade effect:

```
//
// Carousel Fade effect
// --------------------------------------------------

// inspired from http://codepen.io/Rowno/pen/Afykb
.carousel-fade {

    .carousel-inner {
        .item {
            .opacity(0);
            .transition-property(opacity);
            //.transition-duration(.8s);
        }

        .active {
            .opacity(1);

            &.left,
            &.right {
                left: 0;
                .opacity(0);
                z-index: 1;
            }
        }

        .next.left,
        .prev.right {
            .opacity(1);
        }
    }

    .carousel-control {
        z-index: 2;
    }
}

// WHAT IS NEW IN 3.3: 
// "Added transforms to improve carousel performance in modern browsers."
// now override the 3.3 new styles for modern browsers & apply opacity
@media all and (transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d) {

    .carousel-fade {

        .carousel-inner {

            > .item {
                &.next,
                &.prev,
                &.active.right,
                &.active.left {
                    .opacity(0);
                    .translate3d(0; 0; 0);
                }

                &.next.left,
                &.prev.right,
                &.active {
                    .opacity(1);
                    .translate3d(0; 0; 0);
                }
            }

        }

    }

}
```

The only thing is the transition duration which is not working as expected when longer than .8s (around). Maybe someone has a solution to solve this strange behaviour.

**Note:** The LESS code has `.transition-duration(.8s);` commented, so the default carousel transition duration is used. You can play with the value and see the effect. Longer duration (> 0.8) renders the fade effect less smooth.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out : http://codepen.io/Rowno/pen/Afykb

```
.carousel-fade {
    .carousel-inner {
        .item {
            opacity: 0;
            transition-property: opacity;
        }

    .active {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    .active.left,
    .active.right {
        left: 0;
        opacity: 0;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .next.left,
    .prev.right {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

Works marvellously, I hope it works