# Carousel images not fading out

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently trying to have images fade in / out on my page but they are simply disappearing then fading in the next image rather than beginning to fade in the image above the old one and removing that.

CSS :

```
#mainContent div.activelink {
    position: absolute;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .item {opacity: 0; transition-property: opacity; -webkit-transition-property: opacity; }
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active {opacity: 1;}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.left {left: 0; opacity: 0.5; z-index: 1;}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.right {left: 0; opacity: 0; z-index: 1;}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .next.left, .carousel-fade .carousel-inner .prev.right {opacity: 1;}

.carousel-inner > .item {


    -webkit-transition: 3s ease-in-out left;
    -moz-transition: 3s ease-in-out left;
    -o-transition: 3s ease-in-out left;
    transition: 3s ease-in-out left;

}
```

HTML

```
<div class="activelink" id="link-6" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalVideo-trailer">
                            <div id="carousel-link-6" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
                                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                                  <div class="item active"><a href="#"><img src="images/grouptrailer-1.png" alt=""></a></div>
                                  <div class="item"><a href="#"><img src="images/grouptrailer-2.png" alt=""></a></div>
                                  <div class="item"><a href="#"><img src="images/grouptrailer-3.png" alt=""></a></div>
                                  <div class="item"><a href="#"><img src="images/grouptrailer-4.png" alt=""></a></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I misunderstood your method of animation, sorry.  You must be using Bootstrap's carousel feature (since I couldn't get your code to work without adding Bootstrap components).  The CSS in the solution in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26907841/4904449) applies to your code.  I added that CSS to your HTML in this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/nuzemejize/2/) (using imgur images for demo purpose) and it works as you intend.

Comment: It uses CSS transitions, not jQuery.