# Move button using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If I click `Contact` button, how do I move the `Close` button below `#panel`? Currently it's `fixed`.

Here's my **demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/25u78gff/

[image: Aim]

```js
jQuery('.sub-menu').addClass('dropdown-menu');

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$('ul.nav li.dropdown, ul.nav li.dropdown-submenu').hover(function() {
    $(this).find(' > .dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn();
}, function() {
    $(this).find(' > .dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut();
});
var abierto = false;
jQuery("#open").click(function() {
    if (!abierto) {
        jQuery("div#panel").slideDown("slow");
        jQuery("#open").html("Close");
        abierto = true;
    } else {
        jQuery("div#panel").slideUp("slow");
        jQuery("#open").html("Contact us");
        abierto = false;
    }
});


});
```

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

body {
    margin: 10px;
    height:3000px;
}

#panel {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        color: #fff;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 3;
        display: none;
        margin-left:10px;
        background:blue;
        padding:15px;
        margin-top: -1px;
        -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
        -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
        -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;
        -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    }

    /*
      Bootstrap Carousel Fade Transition (for Bootstrap 3.3.x)
      CSS from:       http://codepen.io/transportedman/pen/NPWRGq
      and:            http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548731/bootstrap-3-carousel-fading-to-new-slide-instead-of-sliding-to-new-slide
      Inspired from:  http://codepen.io/Rowno/pen/Afykb 
    */
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner .item {
      opacity: 0;
      transition-property: opacity;
    }

    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active {
      opacity: 1;
    }

    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.left,
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.right {
      left: 0;
      opacity: 0;
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner .next.left,
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner .prev.right {
      opacity: 1;
    }

    .carousel-fade .carousel-control {
      z-index: 2;
    }

    /*
      WHAT IS NEW IN 3.3: "Added transforms to improve carousel performance in modern browsers."
      Need to override the 3.3 new styles for modern browsers & apply opacity
    */
    @media all and (transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d) {
        .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.next,
        .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.active.right {
          opacity: 0;
          -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
                  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        }
        .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.prev,
        .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.active.left {
          opacity: 0;
          -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
                  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        }
        .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.next.left,
        .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.prev.right,
        .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.active {
          opacity: 1;
          -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
                  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    .shortcode input[type="text"], 
    .shortcode input[type="email"], 
    .shortcode input[type="url"], 
    .shortcode input[type="password"], 
    .shortcode input[type="search"], 
    .shortcode select {
        padding: 13px !important;
        width: 100% !important;
        height: 43px !important;
        margin-bottom: 7px !important;
        color: #707070 !important;
        border: 1px solid #c2c2c2 !important;
        font-family: "Crimson Text" !important;
        font-style: italic !important;
        font-size: 14px !important;
        border-radius: 0px !important;
        outline: none !important;
        padding-top: 5px !important;
        padding-bottom: 5px !important;
    }

    .shortcode textarea {
        overflow: auto;
        padding-left: 3px;
        vertical-align: top;
        padding: 15px !important;
        width: 100%;
        height: 142px;
        border-radius: 0px;
        border: 1px solid #c2c2c2 !important;
        margin-bottom: 7px !important;
        color: #707070 !important;
        font-family: "Crimson Text" !important;
        font-style: italic !important;
        font-size: 14px !important;
        outline: none !important;
    }

    input.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-submit {
        border-radius: 0px !important;
        box-shadow: none !important;
        text-shadow: none !important;
        background: #898989 !important;
        color: #fff !important;
        width: 100% !important;
        height: 43px !important;
        outline: none !important;
        font-family: lato !important;
        font-size: 13px !important;
        letter-spacing: 1px !important;
    }

    .carousel-indicators {
        display:none;
    }

    #toppanel {
        position: absolute;
        right: 10px;
        z-index: 400000;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    .tab {
      background:#ccc;
      width:100px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" style="position:relative;z-index: 400000;">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-lg-12">

                <div id="toppanel"> 

                    <div id="panel">

                    <div class="col-lg-8">

                        <p>We check our emails every day and reply even if we’re at dinner! Fill out the form below : )</p>

                        <div role="form" class="wpcf7" id="wpcf7-f60-o1" lang="en-US" dir="ltr">

                        <div class="shortcode">

                            <div role="form" class="wpcf7" id="wpcf7-f233-o1" lang="en-US" dir="ltr">

                                <div class="screen-reader-response"></div>
                                <form name="" action="/contact/#wpcf7-f233-o1" method="post" class="wpcf7-form" novalidate="novalidate">
                                <div style="display: none;">
                                <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7" value="233" />
                                <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_version" value="4.1.2" />
                                <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_locale" value="en_US" />
                                <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_unit_tag" value="wpcf7-f233-o1" />
                                <input type="hidden" name="_wpnonce" value="8d1444dc03" />
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                <div style="float:left; width:49%">
                                <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap name"><input type="text" name="name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Name" /></span><br />
                                <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap surname"><input type="text" name="surname" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Surname" /></span><br />
                                <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap email-404"><input type="email" name="email-404" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Email Address" /></span><br />
                                <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap email-sections"><select name="email-sections" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-select" aria-invalid="false"><option value="I am enquiring about...">I am enquiring about...</option><option value="Design services">Design services</option><option value="Career opportunities">Career opportunities</option><option value="Press &amp; PR">Press &amp; PR</option><option value="General enquiry">General enquiry</option></select></span>
                                </div>
                                <div style="float:right; width:50%">
                                <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap messege"><textarea name="messege" cols="40" rows="10" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Message"></textarea></span><br />
                                <input type="submit" value="SEND" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit" />
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none"></div></form></div>
                                </div>
                            
                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
            
            </div>   

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
    
                <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
                    
                    <div class="container">

                        <div class="col-lg-12">

                            <div class="row">

                                <div class="tab contact-details">
                        
                                    <div>
                                        <a id="open" class="open" href="#">Contact Us</a> 
                                    </div>

                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="navbar-header title">
                            <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="http://localhost:8888/site/"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" class="logoimg"></a>
                            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    
                    </div>

                </nav>

   </div><!-- .site-content -->

  </section>
```

Comment: I'd suggest starting with [formatting your JS correctly](http://jsbeautifier.org). If it's hard to read, it's hard to debug.

Comment: Thanks to Jay, it's looking a lot tidier now :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First:** it's better to use `$(this)` instead of `$('#open')` inside the `.click()`

**Second:** add this to your CSS:

```
.contact-details{ position:relative; }
```

Change your `$('#open').click()` to this

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/25u78gff/11/)

```js
var abierto = false;
jQuery("#open").click(function() {
  if (!abierto) {
    var h = $('#panel').height() + 40;
    jQuery("div#panel").slideDown("slow");
    $(this).html("Close");
    $(this).parents('.contact-details').animate({'top': h}, 600);
    abierto = true;
  } else {
    jQuery("div#panel").slideUp("slow");
    $(this).html("Contact us");
    $(this).parents('.contact-details').animate({'top': 0}, 700);
    abierto = false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When "Contact Us" is click you can add a class to position the button beneath the panel.

CSS

```
.close {
    position:absolute;
    top: 280px;
}
```

Javascript

```
$('.tab').addClass('close');
```

Then remove it when clicked again

```
$('.tab').removeClass('close');
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oo44ywxw/2/)

Comment: This is fantastic!!! Is it possible to move this 'with' the panel so it looks like it's part of it? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Why are you not just adding a button in the panel that toggles the slide? 
This button would "move" with the panel, naturally.  And wouldn't require a jquery at all.

Comment: That's an excellent point. I'm sure I had tried this previously but it didn't work :(

Comment: Creating an internal button also eliminates the need to design the rest of your layout to avoid conflict with the new "close" button location. (if there is more to this page other than what is listed, not sure if that is the case here, just good to keep in mind for streamlining design.)

Comment: It's terrific advice. I'm going to re-consider what I've done so far :-)