# Javascript: Automatic slideshow with navigation bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently looking at this example here:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow_auto

And wanted to know if it is possible to add a link to the navigation bar. Say the slideshow is already on the third image. If I click the second 'dot' in the navigation bar I am instantly taken to the second image, and the automatic image slideshow loop starts from the second image (i.e after 2 seconds it changes to the third, then after another two seconds back to the first and so on).

If anyone could do this (a fiddle would really be appreciated) it would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking for is called a carousel. Use Bootstrap carousel:

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_carousel&stacked=h

For changing the time interval pass the value in JQuery function

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
interval: 1000
});
```

where 1000 is in milliseconds

Comment: Yes, is it possible to have the fade animation effect instead of the slide though?

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548731/bootstrap-3-carousel-fading-to-new-slide-instead-of-sliding-to-new-slide or https://codepen.io/Rowno/pen/Afykb

Comment: The codepen was really helpful. I can't see a way to change the length before it transitions though?

Comment: @SteveJobs check the updated answer, please search the web for all other customization to carousel