# Fade effect into a Bootstrap 3 carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a carousel bootstrap with fade effect, but I am not so expert about this effect. I thought something like this css code

```
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
```

but i don't know how to apply it in my code.

This is my Carousel:

```
   <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="" contenteditable="false"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class="active" contenteditable="false"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class="" contenteditable="false"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item" style="">
            <img src="images/slide/slide-1.jpg" alt="" class="" width="3000px" height="800px">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h4 class="">First Slide Title</h4>
                <p class="">
                   Description for First Slide, this First Slide.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="images/slide/slide-2.jpg" alt="" class="" width="3000px" height="800px">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h4 class="">Second Slide Title</h4>

                <p class="">
                   Description for Second Slide, this is Second Slide.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item" style="">
            <img src="images/slide/slide-3.jpg" alt="" class="" width="3000px" height="800px">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h4 class="">Third Slide Title</h4>

                            <p class="">
                   Description for Third Slide, this is Third Slide.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    

    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    </a>

    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>


</div>
```

and this is my custom.css:

```
.carousel-inner > .item > img, .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
  display: block;
  height: 800px;
  min-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  line-height: 1;   
}
```

Comment: Im not sure but you probably have to put it on the carousel or the parent of the fade item.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I added the class carousel-fade and some custom css
See it in action: http://www.bootply.com/4kbsvxixnA

```
   <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="" contenteditable="false"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class="active" contenteditable="false"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class="" contenteditable="false"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item" style="">
            <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=128&bg=0099ff&txtclr=ffffff&txt=Blue&w=3000&h=800&fm=png" alt="" class="" width="3000px" height="800px">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h4 class="">First Slide Title</h4>
                <p class="">
                   Description for First Slide, this First Slide.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=128&bg=ff33d6&txtclr=ffffff&txt=Pink&w=3000&h=800&fm=png" alt="" class="" width="3000px" height="800px">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h4 class="">Second Slide Title</h4>

                <p class="">
                   Description for Second Slide, this is Second Slide.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item" style="">
            <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=128&bg=97e345&txtclr=ffffff&txt=Green&w=3000&h=800&fm=png" alt="" class="" width="3000px" height="800px">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h4 class="">Third Slide Title</h4>

                            <p class="">
                   Description for Third Slide, this is Third Slide.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
/* YOUR CSS simplified */  
.carousel-inner > .item > img, .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
        display: block;
        height: auto;
        width: 100%;
        line-height: 1;
    }

/*Bootstrap Carousel Fade Transition (for Bootstrap 3.3.x)
  CSS from:       http://codepen.io/transportedman/pen/NPWRGq
  and:            http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548731/bootstrap-3-carousel-fading-to-new-slide-instead-of-sliding-to-new-slide
  Inspired from:  http://codepen.io/Rowno/pen/Afykb*/
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .item {
  opacity: 0;
  transition-property: opacity;
}    
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active {
  opacity: 1;
}    
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.right {
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}    
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .next.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .prev.right {
  opacity: 1;
}    
.carousel-fade .carousel-control {
  z-index: 2;
}

/*WHAT IS NEW IN 3.3: "Added transforms to improve carousel performance in modern browsers."
  Need to override the 3.3 new styles for modern browsers & apply opacity*/
@media all and (transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d) {
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.next,
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.active.right {
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
              transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.prev,
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.active.left {
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
              transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.next.left,
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.prev.right,
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.active {
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
              transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I like your solution and it's working, but I have a big problem: I lost responsive mode... I really don't know what happened... Could you help me?

Comment: In what way? The carousel now has a flexible width and auto height to keep the image aspect ratio. If you replace 'height: auto;' with another value like '300px' or '100%' your image will get squeezed and look funny on different screen sizes.

Comment: Look please: http://www.chiaravercellini.it/test/bootstrap/index.php

Comment: I think som javascript / jQuery is setting the image to width 1850px (inline css). You should fix this. A dirty solution is using !important to override. Like: .carousel-inner > .item > img, .carousel-inner > .item > a > img { width: 100% !important; min-width: 100% !important; }

Comment: It's working! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Add carousel-fade parent class to the

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade">
```

**and add the following css to your custom css stylesheet.**

```
.carousel.carousel-fade .item {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    opacity:0;
}

.carousel.carousel-fade .active.item {
    opacity:1;
}

.carousel.carousel-fade .active.left,
.carousel.carousel-fade .active.right {
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}

.carousel.carousel-fade .next,
.carousel.carousel-fade .prev {
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.carousel.carousel-fade .carousel-control {
    z-index: 3;
}
```

> I have used dummy images from bootstrap to create a demo showing the
>   fade behavior.

```css
.carousel.carousel-fade .item {
 -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
 transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
 opacity:0;
}

.carousel.carousel-fade .active.item {
 opacity:1;
}

.carousel.carousel-fade .active.left,
.carousel.carousel-fade .active.right {
 left: 0;
 z-index: 2;
 opacity: 0;
 filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}

.carousel.carousel-fade .next,
.carousel.carousel-fade .prev {
 left: 0;
 z-index: 1;
}

.carousel.carousel-fade .carousel-control {
 z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="" contenteditable="false"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class="active" contenteditable="false"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class="" contenteditable="false"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item" style="">
            <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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" alt="" class="">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h4 class="">First Slide Title</h4>
                <p class="">
                   Description for First Slide, this First Slide.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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" alt="" class="">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h4 class="">Second Slide Title</h4>

                <p class="">
                   Description for Second Slide, this is Second Slide.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item" style="">
            <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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" alt="" class="" >
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h4 class="">Third Slide Title</h4>

                            <p class="">
                   Description for Third Slide, this is Third Slide.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    

    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    </a>

    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>


</div>
```

Comment: I tried your good solution, but my carousel is not responsive and I don't know why... any suggestion please?

Comment: give the carousel img width:100%;