# carousel change text when affix triggers

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a project that's a bit like a news page and I manage to make the news show in a carousel (without images, only text) and now I added an affix to the carousel so when I scroll down keeps changing the news... However I want to format the text when the affix triggers because it looks quite small. 
Any idea on how I could display the text in one line instead of two?
I almost forgot, is there any way to make the affix with a 2% margin ? I have been trying but it only makes the margin in one part of the screen...

```css
body{
  height: 100%;
}

#divHead{
  margin:1%!important;
  background-image: url(../img/bhead.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color:white;
}
#myCarousel{
  background-color:rgba(144,195,212,0.2);
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left:2%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  color:aliceblue;
}

.divNoticias{
  margin: 1%;
  text-align: center;

}
#newsImg{
  max-height: 200px;
  max-width: 200px;
}


#divAire{
  margin: 1% !important;
}

.mid{
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
}

/*
  Bootstrap Carousel Fade Transition (for Bootstrap 3.3.x)
  CSS from:       http://codepen.io/transportedman/pen/NPWRGq
  and:            http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548731/bootstrap-3-carousel-fading-to-new-slide-instead-of-sliding-to-new-slide
  Inspired from:  http://codepen.io/Rowno/pen/Afykb 
*/
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .item {
  opacity: 0;
  transition-property: opacity;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.right {
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .next.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .prev.right {
  opacity: 1;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-control {
  z-index: 2;
}

/*
  WHAT IS NEW IN 3.3: "Added transforms to improve carousel performance in modern browsers."
  Need to override the 3.3 new styles for modern browsers & apply opacity
*/
@media all and (transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d) {
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.next,
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.active.right {
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
              transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.prev,
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.active.left {
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
              transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.next.left,
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.prev.right,
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.active {
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
              transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
}

.item {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    .transition(5s ease-in-out left);
}

.affix {
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;  
      margin:0!important;
      left:0!important;
      background-color:rgba(144,195,212,1)!important;
      z-index: 9999!important;
     animation: affixFadeIn 3s  ease-in;
      -webkit-animation: affixFadeIn 3s;
      height: 50px;
}
.affix .item h3{
  margin-top:10px;
  font-size: 1vw!important;
}

.affix .item p{
  margin-top: 0px !important;
  font-size: 0.75vw!important;
}


@keyframes affixFadeIn
{
from {opacity: 0;}
to {opacity: 1;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes affixFadeIn 
{
from {opacity: 0;}
to {opacity: 1;}
}


  .affix + .container-fluid {
      padding-top: 70px;
  }

.divPublicidad{
  width: 300px;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  margin-right: 1% !important;
  height: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Noticias Creativas de gente que se entero tres días después</title>
<meta name="description" content="Página web de noticias que es gestionada por personas que no sabían muy bien de que iba esto del periodismo y mantener a las personas informadas.">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!--Boostrap-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--my css-->
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 961px)' href='css/desc.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (max-width: 960px)' href='css/desc.css'>
</head>
<body>

<div id="divHead" class="jumbotron text-center"><h1>NoticiasNET</h1>
    <br>
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="330">
  <!-- Carousel de noticias hemos de implementar leer del JSON tmb -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
        <h3>Los Angeles</h3>
        <p>LA is always so much fun!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h3>Chicago</h3>
        <p>Thank you, Chicago!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">     
        <h3>New York</h3>
        <p>We love the Big Apple!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="divPublicidad"></div>
<div class="divNoticias">
  <h3>Noticia Sobre cosas raras</h3>
  <p>pequeña descripcion de la noiticia que mola mucho aunque no lo creas</p>
  <p> fecha y hora</p>
</div>
<div class="divNoticias">
  <img>
  <h3>Noticia Sobre cosas raras</h3>
  <p>pequeña descripcion de la noiticia que mola mucho aunque no lo creas</p>
  <p> fecha y hora</p>
</div>
<div class="divNoticias">
  <img>
  <h3>Noticia Sobre cosas raras</h3>
  <p>pequeña descripcion de la noiticia que mola mucho aunque no lo creas</p>
  <p> fecha y hora</p>
</div>

<div class="divNoticias">
  <h3>Noticia Sobre cosas raras</h3>
  <p>pequeña descripcion de la noiticia que mola mucho aunque no lo creas</p>
  <p> fecha y hora</p>
</div>
<div class="divNoticias">
  <img>
  <h3>Noticia Sobre cosas raras</h3>
  <p>pequeña descripcion de la noiticia que mola mucho aunque no lo creas</p>
  <p> fecha y hora</p>
</div>
<div class="divNoticias">
  <img>
  <h3>Noticia Sobre cosas raras</h3>
  <p>pequeña descripcion de la noiticia que mola mucho aunque no lo creas</p>
  <p> fecha y hora</p>
</div>

<div id="divPub>licidadMovil"><p>publicidad</p></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have CSS that's overwriting the font size.

```
.affix .item h3{
margin-top:10px;
font-size: 1vw!important;
}
```

Change the value for *font-size* on this to change the font size.

Update: You can change the H3 and P tags to be display inline block.

Below example is the H3 tag:

```
.affix .item h3 {
margin-top: 10px;
font-size: 1vw !important;
display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Yes I know, but I don't want to change the font size but the format that's being shown, lets say that I want to see this: Los Angeles - Text text (in one line)

Comment: Your question was `However I want to format the text when the affix triggers because it looks quite small.`? If you want to change the margin you can do it thru the same CSS. Did you want something else in your question?

Comment: yes sorry, I'm a bit asleep and made the wrong question. As formating the text I was trying to say changing the text order not the size or color etc... I want to h3 to be shown next to the <p> .
And I tryed to do the margin but it's not working even if I put margin:2%!important;

Comment: I have updated my answer with what you can do, let me know how it goes

Comment: great, adding inline-block on both, h3 and p it worked fine ^^!

Comment: Perfect! I wouldn't mind a one up for the chosen answer ;-)