# Bootstrap 3.2.0 vs Bootstrap 3.3.7, Carousel CSS3 3D transforms

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, firefox, carousel

Image sliding on Bootstrap 3.3.7 has changed somehow from the earlier 3.2.0 version. Sliding isn't continuous, i.e. the next images appears only after the previous has slid away (during the transition only the background is visible). This seems to be issue especially on Firefox: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/15534

Where it says that: "`@media all and (transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d)` evaluates to false in Firefox.

There are also some other questions and answers where is mentioned that something regarding to transitions has changed in Bootstrap 3.3.7. For example [Bootstrap 3 Carousel fading to new slide instead of sliding to new slide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548731/bootstrap-3-carousel-fading-to-new-slide-instead-of-sliding-to-new-slide/26907841#26907841) says: "*Added transforms to improve carousel performance in modern browsers.*"

### I found three working solutions

1. Remove the code block `@media all and (transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d) {}` from the v3.3.7 bootstrap.css file (the block starts somewhere on the line 6263 in the non-minified bootstrap.css file)
2. Create a new declaration for the code block: `@media all (transform-3d), all (-webkit-transform-3d) {}`
3. Duplicate the code block content under two declarations: `@media all (transform-3d) {}` and `@media all (-webkit-transform-3d) {}`

### The questions

Is it harmful to take the code block away? Are the new CSS declarations valid? Is there some other completely different solution?

Comment: Yes it is ... you should NOT try to modify the framework code .. the maintainability will go for a toss. Instead, create a new class with the css properties you need to over-write and add the class to the element.

Comment: However I dont see the issue that you have mentioned in the Bootstrap carousel...[https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#carousel)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the issue on Firefox & this solved the issue for me

```
.item.item-moz {
    -moz-perspective: 1000px;
}
```

Add `item-moz` class to all the slides (`.item`) of the carousel inside the `.carousel-inner` element.

Adding the `-moz` prefix for the `perspective` property fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Doesn't work for me if you mean that every direct child `div` of `carousel-inner` `div` should have both classes: "`item item-moz`".

Comment: Yes .. .all the slides should have the classes.

Comment: Yep, tried that, didn't work. Funny if it works for you.

Comment: It worked for me. I just opened the [https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#carousel) in Firefox and made those changes using the developer tool.

Comment: I tried it again and got it working ... I have a screenshot for it .. but not sure how I can show it to you

Comment: That's really odd. I got it working on with Developer tools but not with source code. Despite that Developer tools says: "Can't use  `-moz-perspective: 1000px;`"